# MongoDB Index Strategy for Path Based Document Sorting

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

Given a set of documents that looks like the following, what is the best strategy to create sort index on a top level sort key if there are a indeterminate number of paths in the subdocument?

```
{_id: 1, title: "Document 1", sort:{somePathA: 3, somePathB: 1, somePathC: 3}}
{_id: 2, title: "Document 2", sort:{somePathA: 1, somePathB: 2, somePathC: 2}}
{_id: 3, title: "Document 3", sort:{somePathA: 2, somePathB: 3, somePathC: 1}}
```

For example, the following command:

```
db.find().sort({'sort.somePathC': 1});
```

Should produce the following output:

```
{_id: 3, title: "Document 3", sort:{somePathA: 2, somePathB: 3, somePathC: 1}}
{_id: 2, title: "Document 2", sort:{somePathA: 1, somePathB: 2, somePathC: 2}}
{_id: 1, title: "Document 1", sort:{somePathA: 3, somePathB: 1, somePathC: 3}}
```

Comment: you mean that, the `sort`  embedded document  field can be a doc with a variable nr of felds?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. also, the embedded sort document can vary from document to document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there may a field with the name somePathK in `Sort` subdocument and maybe not. The number of members is not a constant and is dynamic. If i understood correctly, you need to run [`db.collection.createIndex({'sort.somePathK':1},{background:true, sparse:true})`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) function when a new member join to the subdocument. The function creates an index if the index is not found. [Sparse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) expression is needed because of the embedded sort document can vary from document to document.

Then `find().sort({'sort.fieldName': 1})` method can be used efficiently.

On the other hand server [RAM size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/) should be considered to performance.

The case seems hard to manage. So the unknown number of indexes mean the unknown size of RAM is needed. I think the same considerations are equally applicable to the all other database systems.

For good performance, indexes are needed and to store sorted indexes, fit RAM is needed.

Good luck..